# Flutter - How get documents from Cloud Firestore ordering by geo distance?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I have a dating app similar to Tinder but for specific niche, the app stores the latitude and longitude from the user in his document on Cloud Firestore database, I have a method that returns the distance from a user in meters, I am using GeoLocator for that and with this I know the distance between the current user and another user.

```
static String getDistanceBetween({
    double sourceLat, 
    double sourceLong,
    double currentLat,
    double currentLong
      }) {

    double _distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
      sourceLat,
      sourceLong,
      currentLat,
      currentLong,
    );

    print(_distanceInMeters);

    if(_distanceInMeters == null){
      return "?";
    } else if(_distanceInMeters == 0.0){
      return "0";
    } else {
     return _distanceInMeters.toString().substring(0, 5);
    }


  }
```

When the user log in, I wanted to retrieve the nearest users first, what is the easiest way to retrieve documents from nearest users from the current user logged in?

If I could do something like this I think it solves the problem but I don't think it's possible to do with Firestore:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").orderBy(getDistanceBetween(), descending: true).get().then((querySnapshot){

...
/// Get documents from users that are nearest to the current user

})
```

[image: Firestore Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to order by distance, as that requires the database to perform a calculation for each document, which would make it impossible to meet its performance guarantees.

What you can do is retrieve the documents within a certain range from the second user. This is described in the Firestore documentation on [geoqueries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries), but you can also read some of these previous [questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+distance), many of which use add-on libraries to accomplish the same.

Once you've retrieved the documents within the range, you'll then need to order them by their distance in your application code.